# Free or Low-Cost Video Booth software

Tags: gratis, open-source

I am in charge of developing software for a video booth, but am wondering if there are any existing alternatives.

Users would enter a booth and record themselves. The interface should be as simple as possible, with options for record and stop recording. Any video processing would be done outside of the booth with another program, so the fewer the options for the user, the better.

If there are any available web development packages for browser-based video recording, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into WebRTC. Here is a fine tutorial on how you can use WebRTC to gain access to your users' webcams: https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2014/03/13/build-a-local-webcam-with-webrtc-in-less-than-20-lines/